PrimeNG 19 - Changing background color to headers and footers
I’ve been using PrimeNG since Angular 4.  I updated my apps to Angular 18 and PrimeNG 17, because PrimeNG was late in updating.  This week I updated my first app with the latest 19 both Angular and PrimeNG.  I’m having difficulty in getting the theme completely configured.  I’ve only found this article 'Dark theme switch in Angular with PrimeNG 18 and Tailwind', the PrimeNG Theming documentation and the PrimeNG source on github.  I've had some progress, but I'm currently stuck on the setting the background and text colors of the dialog header and footer (see bottom of code).  This is what I've got:
  setLocale( config: PrimeNG, locale: string ): void {
    ...
    const laraPreset = definePreset(Lara, {
        primary: {
          50: '{blue.50}',
          100: '{blue.100}',
          200: '{blue.200}',
          300: '{blue.300}',
          400: '{blue.400}',
          500: '{blue.500}',
          600: '{blue.600}',
          700: '{blue.700}',
          800: '{blue.800}',
          900: '{blue.900}',
          950: '{blue.950}'
        },
        colorScheme: {
          light: {
            primary: {
              color: '{blue.500}',
              inverseColor: '#ffffff',
              hoverColor: '{blue.600}',
              activeColor: '{blue.700}'
            },
            highlight: {
              background: '{blue.500}',
              focusBackground: '{blue.500}',
              color: '#ffffff',
              focusColor: '#ffffff'
            }
          },
          dark: {
            primary: {
              color: '{blue.50}',
              inverseColor: '{blue.950}',
              hoverColor: '{blue.100}',
              activeColor: '{blue.200}'
            },
            highlight: {
              background: 'rgba(250, 250, 250, .16)',
              focusBackground: 'rgba(250, 250, 250, .24)',
              color: 'rgba(255,255,255,.87)',
              focusColor: 'rgba(255,255,255,.87)'
            }
          }
        },
      },
      components: {
        menubar: {
          colorScheme: {
            light: {
              root: {
                background: '{blue.500}',
                color: '{blue.950}',
                borderColor: '{blue.500}',
              }
            },
            dark: {
              root: {
                background: '{blue.600}',
                color: '{blue.50}',
                borderColor: '{blue.600}',
              }
            }
          }
        },
        dialog: {
          colorScheme: {
            light: {
              root: {
                background: '{blue.50}',
                color: '{blue.950}',
              },
              header: {
                background: '{blue.300}',
              },
              footer: {
                background: '{blue.300}',
              }
            },
            dark: {
              root: {
                background: '{blue.800}',
                color: '{blue.50}',
              },
              header: {
                background: '{blue.900}',
              },
              footer: {
                background: '{blue.900}',
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    });
    config.theme.set({
      preset: laraPreset,
      options: {
        darkModeSelector: '.p-dark',
      },
    });
  }

Thanks for contributing ...
